# URL Rewrite all calls to external URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've written a simple PHP script on shared hosting and wish to implement some rules in the .htaccess file so that every time my script calls, let's say, http://www.google.com/test1 it will get http://www.otherwebsite.com/test1 instead.

I've used standard URL Rewriting Rules before but didn't need this specific function.

Thank you !

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google first. A search for `Apache URL Rewrite all calls to external URLs` will give you the resources you need.

Comment: Can you write your htaccess file content?

Comment: Pekka, I am doing some reading on the search you suggested but I still cannot find what I am looking for. Yes, I can write my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to redirect all of your URLs to some other domain.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.otherwebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` can **only** rewrite incoming URLs with domain names that resolve to your web server. It has no control over outgoing URLs as these requests are directly going to outgoing web servers (in your example, google.com).

What you probably need is a scripting solution that redirects the user as you desire by hooking in to `onclick` events of all the *external* links. Here's a quick proof of concept with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) but this can be done using standard JavaScript as well.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery global redirector</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://google.com/search?q=jquery">google url would redirect</a><br />
 <a href="http://mysite.com/somepage.php">mysite.com url won't redirect</a>
 <script>
 <!--
   $(function() {
       $("a").click(function(e) {
         var url = e.target.href;
         if(!(url.startsWith("mysite.com") ||
              url.startsWith("http://mysite.com"))) {
            var path = $( '<a />', {href : url} ).prop( 'pathname' );
            window.location.href = "http://otherwebsite.com" + path;
            e.preventDefault();
         }
       });
   });
 //-->
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should probably put the script inside another file (say `redirect.js`) and then include this script selectively in your pages that need such redirection. And don't forget to import *jQuery* as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's an ingenious solution but I need this for a SWF file which checks an external URL. There's no solution for this so I've moved on...